# SublimeLinter not working with java

Tags: java, sublime-text-2

I'm trying to get sublimelinter to work with java so that I can lint my java program, but I don't know what javac -Xlint or what the path is. So my question is, what is PATHs and -xlint?

I've got sublimelinter pointed to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin` for java files, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Sublimelinter doesn't have easy to follow documentation. So here's what I did to get it working for me.

In your sublimetext project file, you have to set up the SublimeLinter object and configure the Java lint settings.

Suppose you have a project structure like so:

```
C:\path\to\projectname
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com
│   │   │       └───yoursite
│   │   ├───resources
│   │   └───webapp
│   │       └───WEB-INF
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───com
│               └───yoursite
└───target
    ├───classes
    │   └───com
    │       └───yoursite
    ├───projectname
    │   ├───META-INF
    │   └───WEB-INF
    │       ├───classes
    │       │   └───com
    │       │       └───yoursite
    │       └───lib
    ├───javadoc-bundle-options
    ├───maven-archiver
    └───surefire
```

- `working_directory` : The absolute path to your work area. (Anyone know how to reference paths in the `folders.path`?) Also, the rest of the paths are relative to this one.
- `lint_args` : arguments passed to javac

  - `-sourcepath` : path to your source files.
  - `classpath` : path to compiled classes.
  - `-Xlint`, `-Xlint:-serial`: `javac` command line options.
  - `{filename}` : SublimeLinter reference to the current file.

From [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

**-Xlint**: Enable all recommended warnings. In this release, all available warnings are recommended.
**-Xlint:serial**: Warn about missing serialVersionUID definitions on serializable classes.

#### **projectname.sublime-project [1](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/wiki/Java-Lint)**

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "C:\\path\\to\\projectname",
            "name": "projectname"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "SublimeLinter":
        {
            "Java":
            {
                "working_directory": "C:\\path\\to\\projectname",
                "lint_args":
                [
                    "-sourcepath", "src/main/java;c:\\some\\absolute\\path",
                    "-classpath", "C:\\Users\\UERNAME\\.m2\\repository\\path\\to\\file.jar;target/classes",
                    "-Xlint", "-Xlint:-serial",
                    "{filename}"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Way too much in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply add to your CLASSPATH the folders containing the classes you are using.